# Can anyone help me with statistics?

Tags: statistics

**Question:** Following is the distribution of marks obtained by 500 candidates in the statistics paper of a civil services examination:

```
+ marks more than:      0   10  20  30  40  50
+ number of candidates: 500 460 400 200 100 30
```

Calculate the lower quartile marks. If $70\%$ of the candidates pass in the paper, find the minimum marks obtained by a passing candidate.

In the above problem, I am able to find the first part to calculate lower quartile marks but not able to find the second section.

Anyone, please help I am a newbie to statistics.

Thanks in advance, please ignore the bad English.

Comment: What did you get as the lower quartile marks? How?

Comment: @Henry  The lower quartile marks I found was 21.25. I found it by simple quartile formula i.e. Q1 = l + (h/f)(N/4 + C), where h is the magnitude, f is the frequency, N is the total frequency, C is the previous modal class cumulative frequency.

Comment: If you used $0.3 \times N$ rather than $0.25 \times N$, this might give the point with $70\%$ of people at or above that point

Comment: Yeah, but how did you choose 0.3 x N specifically?

Comment: You want $70\%$ of candidates to be above the mark so $30\%$ or $0.3$ of them below

Answer (score 1):

Write out the cumulative distribution function $P(N \leq m)$ for number of candidates N and marks m, by subtracting the numbers given from 500 and dividing by 500.
You can compute what is required by simple interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

70% of 500 is 350. So the top 350 candidates passed the paper.

If the passing grade were 30 or more, this wouldn't be possible, since then only 200 candidates could have passed, at most. If the passing grade were 20 or less, it wouldn't be possible since then at least 400 students would have passed. So the passing grade is somewhere between 21 and 29 inclusive. However, it's impossible to know exactly what it is. Maybe by "the minimum" marks, they mean 21, the lowest the passing grade could possibly be?

Comment: You are precisely right, but If you can help me find the exact value. That would be really helpful.

Comment: @KushSingla You're not stupid, it really is impossible to work out the exact value. I would guess they're looking for 21, but it would depend on how the original question is phrased.